# How to make WPF label side by side?

Tags: c#, wpf

I am trying to put 2 label in stackpanel (Which is in grid) side by side but it's not wokring. the 2nd label come to the 2nd line.

I tried 2 textblock in content property but it doesn't work. I try settting Orientation and ContentAlignment mention in stackoverflow doesn't make any changes.

The first label is bold and another one is normal. Anyone have any idea how to make it work.

Here is the code.

```
 <Label  Style="{StaticResource FormHead}">
                    <Label.Content>
                       <TextBlock>aaa</TextBlock>
                        <TextBlock>bbb</TextBlock>
                    </Label.Content>
                    </Label>
```

Comment: StackPanel has an Orientation property... Alternatively, add a Bold and a Run to the Inlines collection of a TextBlock, like `<TextBlock><Bold><Run Text="aaa"/></Bold><Run Text="bbb"/></TextBlock>`

Comment: Or `<TextBlock><Bold>aaa</Bold><Run>bbb</Run></TextBlock>`

Answer (score 5):

```
You can simply do it as below :
<StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
    <TextBlock>aaa</TextBlock>
    <TextBlock>bbb</TextBlock>
</StackPanel>
```

Answer (score 3):

Try this.

```
<Label>
    <Label.Content>
       <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
           <TextBlock>aaa</TextBlock>
           <TextBlock>bbb</TextBlock>
       </StackPanel>
    </Label.Content>
</Label>
```